# Logical check: Find first item in a run of one or more

Tags: r

I am trying to efficiently (reduced code and reduced run time) find a way to generate a logical check of all elements of a vector.  I'd prefer base answers but for the generalizability of the question all solutions are welcomed.  If an element is the first of in a run then it's `TRUE` else it's `FALSE`.  I have done so with some ugly code.  I could `magrittr` it but the code still seems unwieldy for the simple task:

**My Ugly Code**

```
set.seed(3)
(x <- sample(1:3, 15, TRUE))
## [1] 1 3 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3

y <- rle(as.character(x))
(out <- unlist(lapply(split(rep(FALSE, length(x)), rep(paste0("x",
    seq_along(y[[1]])), y[[1]])), function(x) {x[1] <- TRUE; x}), use.names = FALSE))
```

**Desired output**

```
data.frame(x, out)

##    x   out
## 1  1  TRUE
## 2  3  TRUE
## 3  2  TRUE
## 4  1  TRUE
## 5  2  TRUE
## 6  2 FALSE
## 7  1  TRUE
## 8  1 FALSE
## 9  2  TRUE
## 10 2 FALSE
## 11 2 FALSE
## 12 2 FALSE
## 13 2 FALSE
## 14 2 FALSE
## 15 3  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest `diff`:

```
myout <- c(TRUE,diff(x)!=0)

identical(out,myout) # TRUE
```

---

As far as speed goes, I guess it could depend on how long your runs are. `rle` just makes one pass of the vector, while `diff` and `!=` are two. To get the positions of the TRUE values out of `y <- rle(x)`, you can use

```
length(x)+1-cumsum(rev(y$lengths))
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about.  I knew there was some simplicity I was not able to attain.  I'll check in 6 mins when I can.